# Arrow operator in C (pointer and structure) error

Tags: c, pointers, struct

As you can see in this part of my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct s_box
{
    int matnr;
    double vol;
    int pos[2];
};

int main ()
{
    int matnr2;
    double vol2;
    int pos2[2];

    typedef struct s_box *pt_box;
    pt_box *p,*q;

    p = (pt_box *)malloc(sizeof(pt_box));
    q = (pt_box *)malloc(sizeof(pt_box));

    printf("Write a value for: \nMaterialnr= ");
    scanf("%d",&matnr2);

    printf("\nVolumen = ");
    scanf("%fl",&vol2);

    printf("\nxPos =");
    scanf("%d",&pos2[0]);

    printf("\nyPos =");
    scanf("%d",&pos2[1]);

    printf("\nzPos =");
    scanf("%d",&pos2[2]);
    //on the next line is my question:
    p -> matnr =  matnr2; //Codeblox gives me the next "error:'*p' is a pointer; did you mean to use '->'?"
    p->vol = vol2;//same error
    p->pos = pos2[0],pos2[1],pos2[2]);//same error
    printf("MaterialNr = \t%d/nVolumen = \t%f m^3\nPosition = (%d,%d,%d)",p->matnr,p->vol,p->pos[0],p->pos[1],p->pos[2]);
    // my target is to print the data stored in *p on the screen.
}
```

So the question is about the error: "did you mean to use '->'?" I already use it and Codeblox does not accept it. So what do I have to change and print the data on the screen after entering it from the keyboard.

P.S. I started learning C one week ago.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To address the *specific* error in your question (there are others in your code): the issue lies in these two lines:

```c
    typedef struct s_box *pt_box;
    pt_box *p,*q;
```

Here, you have defined the type `pt_box` as a pointer to an `s_box` structure; so, when you declare `pt_box *p` then `p` is a pointer to a pointer! So, to use the `->` operator on that variable, you would first need to remove one level of referencing; so, for example:

```c
    (*p)->vol = vol2;
```

However, what you really want is not to have that 'second level' indirection, so just declare your `p` and `q` variables as of 'plain' `pt_box` type (already a structure pointer), like so:

```c
    typedef struct s_box* pt_box;
    pt_box p, q; // p and q are now POINTERS to s_box structures
    p = malloc(sizeof(struct s_box)); // Must be the size of the structure, not the pointer!
    q = malloc(sizeof(struct s_box)); // See note below!
```

---

Further, you can't assign entire arrays with one `=` operator, as you are attempting here:

```c
    p->pos = pos2[0], pos2[1], pos2[2]); // Wrong, even without the odd ")" character!
```

Instead, you need to assign each element separately:

```c
    p->pos[0] = pos2[0];  p->pos[1] = pos2[1]; // See below on the `pos[2]` third element!!
```

---

Another point: please see this Q/A: [Do I cast the result of malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/10871073). Also, a more 'shorthand' way of getting the correct size on the calls to `malloc` is to use the 'dereference' of the destination variable; so, instead of the 'clumsy' `sizeof(struct s_box)`, you could use `*p` and `*q`, like this:

```c
    p = malloc(sizeof(*p));
    q = malloc(sizeof(*q));
```

---

And one more error that I found: You can only store **two** values in the array `pos[2]`! To get the `z` position, you will need to have *three* elements, so make the member `int pos[3]` (as also with the `pos2` variable).

Please feel free to ask for any further clarification and/or explanation.

Comment: Added to that, `scanf("%fl",&vol2)` is wrong or a `double` argument `vol2`. The correct format specifier is `%lf`

Comment: @WhozCraig Yes - slowly working through other errors, too (see latest edit).